# How to remove certain string from column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string

I want to remove a certain keywords or string in a column from pandas dataframe.

The dataframe `df` looks like this:

```
YEAR    WEEK
2019    WK-01
2019    WK-02
2019    WK-03
2019    WK-14
2019    WK-25
2020    WK-06
2020    WK-07
```

I would like to remove `WK-`and `0` from the `WEEK` column so that my output will looks like this:

```
YEAR    WEEK
2019    1
2019    2
2019    3
2019    14
2019    25
2020    6
2020    7
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
df['WEEK'] = df['WEEK'].str.extract('(\d*)$').astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   YEAR  WEEK
0  2019     1
1  2019     2
2  2019     3
3  2019    14
4  2019    25
5  2020     6
6  2020     7
```

Answer (score 3):

Shave off the first three characters and convert to int.

```
df['WEEK'] = df['WEEK'].str[3:].astype(int)
```

Comment: what's the different between using the `str.extract` and only `str`?

Comment: @NurAtiqah `str.extract` lets you extract matches from regular expressions. `str[...]` allows vectorized access to specific elements or slices of elements.

Comment: noted...so..if I were to combine this output to the original dataframe that has multiple column...I can use `join()` right?